# Not Function And Function Composition in F#

Tags: function, lambda, f#, functional-programming, function-composition

Is it possible it F# to have function composition between `Operators.Not` and some standard .NET function, for instance `String.IsNullOrEmpty`?

In other words, why is the following lambda expression unacceptable:

```
(fun x -> not >> String.IsNullOrEmpty)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `>>` function composition works the other way round - it passes the result of the function on the left to the function on the right - so your snippet is passing `bool` to `IsNullOrEmpty`, which is a type error. The following works:

```
(fun x -> String.IsNullOrEmpty >> not)
```

Or you can use reversed function composition (but I think `>>` is generally preferred in F#):

```
(fun x -> not << String.IsNullOrEmpty)
```

Aside, this snippet is creating a function of type `'a -> string -> bool`, because it is ignoring the argument `x`. So I suppose you might actually want just:

```
(String.IsNullOrEmpty >> not)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use argument `x`, you can use pipe operator `|>` instead of function composition operators (`<<` or `>>`).

```
fun x -> x |> String.IsNullOrEmpty |> not
```

But point-free style with function composition is generally preferred.